# How to create new df column from strings of another rows with conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataFrame with names and types. I need to create "newType"-column using  shift for "Type"- column.
My dataFrame:

```
ind   name    Type
____________________
1     sasha   a      
2     sasha   e
3     sasha   d
4     sasha   t
5     sasha   t
6     sasha   w
7     nik     e
8     nik     e
9     nik     q
10    nik     t
11    nik     h
12    nik     j
13    bob     k
14    bob     y
15    bob     r
16    bob     w
17    bob     t
18    bob     w
```

I need to create new column using window = n for "Type"-column with condition for "name"-column. If rows in my window have different names we return NaN.

window size = 3, window look like this

[Type[i-1] , Type[i] , Type[i+1] ]

size = 4

[Type[i-2] , Type[i-1] , Type[i] , Type[i+1] ]

size = 5

[Type[i-3], Type[i-2] , Type[i-1] , Type[i] , Type[i+1] ]

...etc

Illustration for window = 4:
Picture:
[Algorithm visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUWLO.png)

Result that I need:

```
ind   name    Type   newType
____________________________
1     sasha   a       NaN 
2     sasha   e       NaN
3     sasha   d       aedt
4     sasha   t       edtt
5     sasha   t       dttw
6     sasha   w       NaN
7     nik     e       NaN
8     nik     e       NaN
9     nik     q       eeqt
10    nik     t       eqth
11    nik     h       qthj
12    nik     j       NaN
13    bob     k       NaN
14    bob     y       NaN
15    bob     r       kyrw
16    bob     w       yrwt
17    bob     t       rwtw
18    bob     w       NaN
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not done in the most efficient way, but then again this is somewhat of a complicated operation. I tried for some time to use [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) or expanding functions, but to no avail (since they seem to only work on numerical arguments). Here is my method to attain the desired output:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Make DataFrame
df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""ind   name    Type
1     sasha   a      
2     sasha   e
3     sasha   d
4     sasha   t
5     sasha   t
6     sasha   w
7     nik     e
8     nik     e
9     nik     q
10    nik     t
11    nik     h
12    nik     j
13    bob     k
14    bob     y
15    bob     r
16    bob     w
17    bob     t
18    bob     w"""), sep='\s+')
def joiner(r):
    return "-".join(r.values)
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
# Make new column which join letters aggregated by name
df['full_join'] = df.groupby('name')['Type'].apply(joiner)
df['full_join'].ffill(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
a = df.full_join.str.split("-",expand=True)
b = []
w = 4 # window
# This part is probably not as efficient as it could be
for i in range(len(a)):
    j = i % len(a.iloc[i].str.split('-'))
    b.append("".join(a.iloc[i,j-(w-1):j+1].tolist()))
df['result'] = b
df['result'] = df['result'].shift(-1)
df.loc[df['result'] == "", 'result'] = np.nan
df.drop(columns=['full_join'], inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
Out[135]: 
     name  ind Type result
0   sasha    1    a    NaN
1   sasha    2    e    NaN
2   sasha    3    d   aedt
3   sasha    4    t   edtt
4   sasha    5    t   dttw
5   sasha    6    w    NaN
6     nik    7    e    NaN
7     nik    8    e    NaN
8     nik    9    q   eeqt
9     nik   10    t   eqth
10    nik   11    h   qthj
11    nik   12    j    NaN
12    bob   13    k    NaN
13    bob   14    y    NaN
14    bob   15    r   kyrw
15    bob   16    w   yrwt
16    bob   17    t   rwtw
17    bob   18    w    NaN
```

Pleasantly surprised that this ended up also working for other windows (I've tested 2, 3 and 5). Unfortunately failing when adding a row to nik :(